# HTML5 Validating with Nu Html Checker

Tags: html, validating

I am validating an HTML5 page and is returning these 2 warnings:
Info: The Content-Type was text/html. Using the HTML parser.
Info: Using the schema for HTML with SVG 1.1, MathML 3.0, RDFa 1.1, and ITS 2.0 support.

I'm not sure if the problem is about the meta tag.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Home Page</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
```

Thanks in advance,
CA

Comment: What “problem” are you talking about? Those are two _infos_, not warnings. They’re just saying which content type and which schema was used for validating.

Comment: FYI: today I published [`linter-vnu`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-vnu), a package for the Atom editor that uses the Nu Html Checker (v.Nu) to validate (X)HTML5 either as you type ("on the fly") or when you save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not warnings.  They are informational notes.

Your document is fine.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply! So I think that these 2 informational notes cannot be arranged? thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome.  What do you mean by "arranged"?  There is nothing you need to do for them.  Any good HTML5 page will give those same info notes.

Comment: aa oki thanks :) Just was worried, but since a good HTML5 page will give those same info notes there are no probs!!